# Jira Query - Search issues which had 2 or more assignees

Tags: jira, jql

How can I search JIRA to show tasks which had two or more assignees over its course.
Basically, need a list of resolved/closed tasks for a period, which had assignees changed in its duration.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Search for all issues where assignee was changed:

```
assignee CHANGED
```